# Find the limit of: $\lim_{z\rightarrow i} = \left|\frac{z^3-i}{z^6+1}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Find the limit of:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i} = \left|\dfrac{z^3-i}{z^6+1}\right|$$

I'm not sure how to do this, thanks for any help.

Edit:

$\lim_{z\rightarrow i} = \left|\dfrac{z^3-i}{z^6+1}\right|  = \lim_{z\rightarrow i}  \left|\dfrac{z^3-i}{(z^3-i)(z^3+i)}\right| = \lim_{z\rightarrow i} \left|\dfrac{1}{(z^3+i)}\right|$

If I plug in $i$ for $z$, wouldn't I still get $\dfrac{1}{0}$?

Comment: You factor and cancel, just like in "calc 1".

Comment: What's wrong with getting 1/0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(z^6 + 1)$ factors as $(z^3 + i)(z^3 - i)$... see it now?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $z^6+1=(z^3+i)(z^3-i)$.

.

Comment: I edited my post, and my question is if I plug in $i$ for $z$, wouldn't I still get $\dfrac{1}{0}$?

Comment: Yes, it will. Then you may conclude the limit does not exist.